# vuejs2 img src attribute binding issue

Tags: vuejs2

i am trying to bind an image source attribute to a computed property like this:

```
// file: ProfileAvatar.vue

<template>
 <div>
    <img :src="image">
 </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: ['profile_user'],
    data() {
        return {
            user: this.profile_user,
            image: 'http://tddforum.com/storage/avatars/avatar.jpg',
        }
    },

    computed: {
        getImageUrl: function(){
            return this.user.avatar_location;
        },
    },
}
</script>
```

It works as long as i am binding the src attribute to the data property **image**. But whenever i am changing the binding from **image** to **getImageUrl** i get console error:

```
// in Firefox
unexpected token: string literal 

//in chrome
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string
```

This is driving me nuts. How to solve this. I saw a post where the solution suggested to wrap the value of src attribute inside the **require()** method. But i did not understand it.

Can anyone help please.

Reg,

Comment: you don't seem to have `avatar_location` in your data

Comment: I do have it. But i am getting very weird behavior. Whenever i am introducing this vue component to my page, i start getting these unexpected token error. on recompiling my files through npm watch it goes away for one time, but reappears in the next page refresh. I had to totally get rid of this vue component just to get my project back to normal. I hate this thing about vue js/front end frameworks. It is extremely hard to debug. Damn it!

Comment: please remove the comment i.e. `//..`

Comment: I need to see more of the code, to help you debug it